# Elixir eunit_formatters failing to compile on Ubuntu

Tags: elixir, exrm

Running mix deps.compile I get the following output:

```
==> eunit_formatters (compile)
Compiling src/eunit_progress.erl failed:
src/eunit_progress.erl:none: undefined parse transform 'eunit_striptests'
ERROR: compile failed while processing /var/www/myapp/releases/20150618041131/deps/eunit_formatters: rebar_abort
** (Mix) Could not compile dependency eunit_formatters, /root/.mix/rebar command failed. If you want to recompile this dependency, please run: mix deps.compile eunit_formatter
```

Running `mix deps.compile eunit_formatter` as it suggests results in the same error.

No clue what to do...

Comment: A better place could be asking here: https://github.com/seancribbs/eunit_formatters/issues

Comment: Btw, may I ask why you need that project from Elixir? Do you have a mixed Elixir/Erlang project?

Comment: Can you compile eunit_formatters using rebar?  It sounds like a problem with the source code and if that's the case you should be able to repro the behavior without mix.

Comment: It got added after adding exrm, not sure why its a needed dependency.

Comment: You need to install the package erlang-eunit using apt-get and it will work.